# Spring REST request with Nested Properties (in Tree structure)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have created spring REST endpoint with below beans,I am not sure what should be type of "values"?

```
class Group
{
private long groupId;
private long groupIndex;
private List<????> values
}
class Sample
{
 private long sampleId;
 private long sampleIndex;
}
```

Some times I get in request "values" as list of groups or list of samples.
example request Json:

Request 1:

```
{
   "groupId": 1,
   "groupIndex": 2,
   "values": [
      {
         "sampleId": 2,
         "sampleIndex": 555
      },
      {
         "sampleId": 3,
         "sampleIndex": 6
      }
   ]
}
```

Request 2:

```
{
   "groupId": 1,
   "groupIndex": 2,
   "values": [
      {
         "groupId": 4,
         "groupIndex": 8,
         "values": [
            {
               "sampleId": 2,
               "sampleIndex": 555
            },
            {
               "sampleId": 3,
               "sampleIndex": 6
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Inheritance could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
public class Group {
  private Long groupId;
  private Long groupIndex;
  private Long sampleId;
  private Long sampleIndex;
  private List<Group> values;
}
```

This is one approach. Not the only one.

Use Long instead of long. So that values are nullable.

Comment: if user send 'values' as 'list of sample' this not work.

Comment: DO you have solution without merging two class properties into one class?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is

```
class Group
{
private long groupId;
private long groupIndex;
private List<Object> values
}
class Sample
{
 private long sampleId;
 private long sampleIndex;
}
```

Then with a custom deserializer, you can either insert the `List` type to either `Group` or `Sample`. IMHO I find this messy and over-complicate the endpoint. I would split the endpoint into 2 different methods that accept different request bodies, but keep the URL the same. Spring should be able to determine which method gets which object type. This only works if it goes one layer deep.

```
class SuperGroup
{
private long groupId;
private long groupIndex;
private List<Group> values
}
class Group
{
private long groupId;
private long groupIndex;
private List<Sample> values
}
class Sample
{
 private long sampleId;
 private long sampleIndex;
}
```

Comment: and like others stated above use the `Long` instead of `long`

Comment: Thanks for alternative solution.Max 2 level of depth possible